# Firebase push notification is not working in firefox 63

Tags: firebase, firefox, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I am trying to implement FCM push notification. And my firefox version is 63.0.

Below is my code,

```
var config = {
                apiKey: "${model.apiKey}",
                authDomain: "${model.authDomain}",
                databaseURL: "${model.databaseURL}",
                projectId: "${model.projectId}",
                storageBucket: "${model.storageBucket}",
                messagingSenderId: "${model.messagingSenderId}"
            };

            firebase.initializeApp(config)
            const messaging = firebase.messaging();
            messaging.requestPermission().then(function () {
            console.log("Notification permission granted.");
           // get the token in the form of promise
            return messaging.getToken()
            }).then(function(token) {
                 $('#devicekey').val(token);
            }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.", err);
   });
```

> Notification permission granted

is showing in the console. But showing an error

> FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's
>   required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).

So that I can't get the token.Why is this so? Please note that am running my application over 'http'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client):

> The FCM SDK is supported only in pages served over HTTPS. This is due to its use  of service workers, which are available only on HTTPS sites. Need a provider? Firebase Hosting is an easy way to get free HTTPS hosting on your own domain.

In my Firefox 63 I saw message like yours when I tried to open a page with firebase initialization via http.
My Chrome writes more specifically warning in this case:

> [Deprecation] The Notification API may no longer be used from insecure origins. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

Also I saw message like yours when I worked in Firefox 60 by https. The reason is that "service workers" [disabled on Firefox 60 ESR](https://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers) (but can be re-enabled). This message is too general in Firefox.